# d3.js - How to achieve pointing-stick-like moving behavior?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drag, mousedown

I want to achieve a a [pointing stick / joystick moving behavior](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3A7LDyizlc) with a touchpad. That is:

1. Having an initial mousedown / dragstart position
2. While mousedown move the finger only by tilting the angle of the finger on the touchpad
3. the offset between initial finger location and the current finger location defines the speed the dragged d3 object is moving
4. The direction of where the finger is tilted to defines the direction the object is moving at
5. on mouseup / dragend the movement is stopped

I tried to achieve it with `setInterval`, but I feel like this is the wrong approach. Someone has any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: this is not how a trackpoint works, how do you know the tilt angle of the finger?

Comment: I don't need the angle. Just the offset from initial click location

Answer (score 0):

I found [this js library](https://yoannmoinet.github.io/nipplejs/) which can achieve the desired behavior. I just pass the variables to the d3 object's positioning every time they change.